# I have to scrape the linkedin website by clicking all the job titles and extract the content and repeat that for 50 subsequent webpages

Tags: python, web-scraping

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep 
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchAttributeException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import numpy as np

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?locationId=sg:0&orig=JSERP&start=0&count=25&trk=jobs_jserp_pagination_1')
result = []

while True:
   try:
       sleep(1)
       jobtitlebutton = driver.find_element_by_class_name('job-title-link')
       jobtitlebutton.click()
       result += driver.find_elements_by_class_name('content')
       driver.navigate().back()
       try:
           nextbutton = driver.find_element_by_class_name('next-btn')
           nextbutton.click()
       except:
           break
   except:
       sleep(2)
```

The issue is, this code can only click the first job title and it stops there. It doesn't scrape the content and navigate to the back page and repeat for the other job titles. There are 50 webpages of job titles.

Comment: Note that recently [100 anonymous people were sued for scraping LinkedIn](http://betanews.com/2016/08/16/linkedin-sues-data-scrapers/). I wouldn't be surprised if they have tools in place to catch naive scraping attempts like this.

Comment: Oh ok but is there anything wrong in the code ? I dont think thats an issue as linkedin doesn't allow to scrape user data but this isn't user data which I am scraping